# Including and excluding indexes in Elasticsearch query

Tags: elasticsearch

I have the following Elasticsearch query.

```
GET /index1,index2/type1,type2/_search?q=programming
```

Let's say that I want to exclude `index2` from this search query. The [documentation states the following](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/multi-index.html#multi-index):

> It also support wildcards, for example: test*, and the ability to
>   "add" (+) and "remove" (-), for example: +test*,-test3.

As far as I understand, I should be able to do the following.

```
GET /+index1,-index2/type1,type2/_search?q=programming
```

However, I get the below error.

```
{
  "error": {
    "root_cause": [
      {
        "type": "index_not_found_exception",
        "reason": "no such index",
        "resource.type": "index_or_alias",
        "resource.id": " index1",
        "index": " index1"
      }
    ],
    "type": "index_not_found_exception",
    "reason": "no such index",
    "resource.type": "index_or_alias",
    "resource.id": " index1",
    "index": " index1"
  },
  "status": 404
}
```

If I remove the plus and minus signs, the query runs fine. If I add a wildcard, it seems to work, e.g. the below query.

```
GET /index1,-*index2/type1,type2/_search?q=programming
```

However, that's not really what I want.

Why is my query not working when I use plus and minus signs to include or exclude indexes as the documentation states? Am I misunderstanding something?

I am using Elasticsearch 2.1.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to **encode** the `+` sign as it is considered `space` in URL string. See there is `space` in `"resource.id": " index1",`

This will work

```
GET /%2Bindex1,-index2/type1,type2/_search?q=programming
```

Hope this helps!!

Comment: I absolutely cannot believe I didn't spot that. I did notice the space in there, but hadn't given it much thought. Well, that was embarrassing! Thanks for the answer! :-)

Comment: I've a similar problem. Minus isn't working. `"resource.id": "-profiles_2"` I've this in the error.