# Exclude index name using mserch query in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I am using elasticsearch to fetch logs using msearch API for multiple indices.
But I need to exclude some indexes. Suppose I have a,b,c,d,e indexes but I don't want to include indexes b,c.

I wrote elasticsearch query to fetch records:

```
GET _msearch?
{"index":"*","size":100000,"exclude":["b","c"]}  //used kibana to check indexes
{"query":{}}  //required to successfully run the query
```

But I am getting records including indexes b,c. I checked the documentation but I didn't get any proper resource for this.
How can I resolve this??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code should do the trick:

```
GET _msearch?
{"index":"*,-b,-c","size":100000}
{"query":{}}
```

Note the minus (`-`) in the `"index"` value.

Although there isn't an explicit mention in the [_msearch](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.5/search-multi-search.html) docs page, it looks like most of the APIs supporting multi index execution [work in the same way](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.5/multi-index.html#multi-index):

> Most APIs that refer to an index parameter support execution across
>   multiple indices, using simple test1,test2,test3 notation (or _all for
>   all indices).
>   It also support wildcards, for example: test* or *test or te*t or
>   *test*, and the ability to "exclude" (-), for example: test*,-test3.

There's a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34578596/including-and-excluding-indexes-in-elasticsearch-query) on search over multiple indexes in general.