# Is there any way to exclude a particular index using cat API in elastic search?

Tags: elasticsearch, curl

I am writing a shell script that will take back-ups. The problem is the argument should be cURL request and the parameter passed with URL should ignore a particular index. I read ES cat API document but was not able to figure out and the other answers give grep as the solution.

health status index
green open abcd 
green open efgh 
green open ijkl 
green open mnop 
green open qrst

Commands Executed is: 
curl -X GET "http://hostname:port/_cat/indices/*,-efgh"
curl -s http://hostname:port/_cat/indices | grep -v "efgh"

I want to ignore efgh while rest of the indices should be printed. Help would be appreciated

Error: {"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"index_not_found_exception","reason":"no such index","resource.type":"index_or_alias","resource.id":"efgh","index_uuid":"*na*","index":"efgh"}],"type":"index_not_found_exception","reason":"no such index","resource.type":"index_or_alias","resource.id":"efgh","index_uuid":"*na*","index":"efgh"},"status":404}

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the following syntax:

```
GET _cat/indices/*,-efgh
```

which means "include everything, but `efgh`"

In curl, it would give this:

```
curl -s -XGET 'hostname:post/_cat/indices/*,-efgh*'
```

Comment: Please update your question to show how you're running this.

Comment: You're missing a `/` before the `*` and you should probably enclose the full URL with double quotes or ticks. Also make sure you're using GET and not POST. See my updated answer

Comment: That was a formatting mistake, I have done exactly the same way as you have written.

Comment: Can you update your question with the full error you get?

Comment: Are you sure that index `efgh` does exist?

Comment: Try to add a star after `efgh` like I did in my updated answer

Comment: It is causing another issue. All indexes that contain efgh are getting deleted. Is there any way to get the exact match ?

Answer (score 0):

GET /%2Bindex1,-index2/type1,type2/_search?q=programming

Look at :

[Including and excluding indexes in Elasticsearch query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34578596/including-and-excluding-indexes-in-elasticsearch-query)

Comment: The OP just needs the index names